# Difference between Socket Programming and Django Form submission

Tags: python, django, sockets, django-forms

i am learning socket programming and Django web developing. As what i know socket is used for the communication between client and server. Dose this mean that when using and submitting Form in Django, there will be a socket created and submitted to the server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Dose this mean that when using and submitting Form in Django, there will be a socket created and submitted to the server?

The short answer: **yes.**

Your terminology is a bit off: a socket isn't "submitted" to the server. A socket is used for sending data to, and receiving data from, somewhere else.

---

The longer answer is of course much more complicated. The *longest* answer fills textbooks.

There are a few layers to peel off here.

- HTML forms are transmitted to the server using [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP).
- HTTP is an **application-layer** protocol which is built on top of [TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol).
- TCP is a **transport layer** protocol (built, of course, on something else).

So, in the simplest case<sup>*</sup>, when the form is submitted, the browser sends an HTTP POST to the server. The browser's HTTP implementation will open a TCP connection to the server, and that's a socket. *Through* that socket, the HTTP message is transmitted, and the server's response is received.

So a socket is a much, *much* lower-level construct than an HTML form.

[From Wikipedia,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:IP_stack_connections.svg) here's a full view of the layers of the networking stack:

[image]

If you find this stuff interesting, I recommend taking a course on computer networking.

---

<sup>*</sup> No [`Connection: Keep-alive`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection), for instance.

Answer (score 1):

The socket is created but not submitted to the server. Django is for HTTP server (port 80 and some other custom used ones). It is a library built around sockets listening/connecting to said port and with extra added features needed in Web development.

Socket programming is more general since it is lower level than Django and it allows using any port number you desire.

On the [ISO OSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model) stack Django stays on level 7 while socket programming is at level 4.

Answer (score 1):

Sockets are just one method of communicating between client and server, but not the method Django is using when processing a form submission. It is most likely sending a HTTP POST request with parameters that the server listens for.

Comment: HTTP uses TCP, which uses sockets.